# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rows') error when accessing this primeNG table with Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress, primeng

We started using primeNG tables and I want to create a function where i access a table to see if certain text elements are present. But i get an error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rows') when i run this.

Please know that the switch statement is work in progress. The error occurs on table.rows(). Anybody an idea to solve this error?

The code is as follows:

```
    verifyTemplatePresent(template: string, table:any) {
        cy.get(this.#templateDataTable, {timeout: 30000}).within(() => {
            table.rows((element:any) => {
                const cellText = element.find('td').eq(0).text();
                switch (cellText === template) {
                    case true:
                        return cy.get(this.fieldTd(element))
                            .should('exist');
                    case false:
                        return cy.get(this.fieldTd(element))
                            .should('not.exist');
                    default:
                        throw new Error("A wrong text was entered in the table, please change it to a correct value");
                }
            });
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `table` variable is in the wrong place, move it down one line.

But `table.rows()` also looks wrong to me. Should it be `table.find('tbody tr')`.

```js
verifyTemplatePresent(template: string) {
  cy.get(this.#templateDataTable, {timeout: 30000}).within((table: any) => { 

    cy.wrap(table).find('tbody tr').each((element:any) => {
```

Comment: Yes, this solved my issue. Now I can go further to check the values in 'td'. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to check that you're correctly passing the PrimeNG table object to the verifyTemplatePresent function.

You can verify this by checking if the table object is defined before attempting to access its properties.

```
verifyTemplatePresent(template: string, table: any) {
  cy.get(this.#templateDataTable, { timeout: 30000 }).within(() => {
    if (table && table.rows) {
      table.rows((element: any) => {
        const cellText = element.find('td').eq(0).text();
        switch (cellText === template) {
          case true:
            return cy.get(this.fieldTd(element)).should('exist');
          case false:
            return cy.get(this.fieldTd(element)).should('not.exist');
          default:
            throw new Error(
              "A wrong text was entered in the table, please change it to a correct value"
            );
        }
      });
    } else {
      throw new Error("The table object is undefined or null");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,  but i had to go one step further like @Aladin Spaz proposed.